# Cannot insert into database using php with PDO:: execute()

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, pdo

I have created a simple mySQL database, and I am trying to insert some test data into it using PHP. When I ran the method on Firefox I got the following message, and I can not resolve this problem:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

My method to insert sample into my datebase is:

```
public function confirmInsert(){
    $admin="admin";
    $pass="12345v";
    $mail="admin@example.com";  
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_name', 'user_pass, 'user_email')
            VALUES (
                    :admin, 
                    :pass,
                    :mail)";
    try {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($insertSQL);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':user_name',$admin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':user_pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_email', $mail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return TRUE;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e -> getMessage();
        }
}
```

I am running on //localhost, and using apache 2.2 and php 5.2.17. Thanks!!

Comment: You have an unmatched opening single quote: `'user_pass`

Comment: @icktoofay: and even more - there shouldn't be single quotes at all, but backticks (or nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'You don't have the same name for your parameters in the query and when you bind them. You also have to remove the quotes around the fields name in the query.

Should be better that way:

```
public function confirmInsert(){
    $admin='admin';
    $pass='12345v';
    $mail='admin@example.com';  
    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pass, user_email)
            VALUES (
                    :admin, 
                    :pass,
                    :mail)";
    try {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($insertSQL);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':admin',$admin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt ->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $mail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return TRUE;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e -> getMessage();
        }
}
```

Comment: with your change, it does get rid of the error message, but it still doesnt insert anything into the database. The column names as you can see in the prepare string are: 'user_name', 'user_pass, 'user_email'. When binding with bindParam, admin, pass, mail, respectively, are we changing the column names??

Comment: No the column names stay the same, you add some errors in the usage of quotes, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have the rights to make comments, so i have to post this as an answer..

R.E. Pompom6784's answer, using `bindParam()` the variable name need not match the parameter:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $admin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Should work just fine.

You are binding `:user_name` to accept **only** the variable named `$admin`

..if that makes things a bit clearer.

If you would like some more information on this topic, here's a good article to read through:

[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

It includes examples where it is necessary to have matching variable and placeholder names.